# C++ queue with 2 threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am using a queue with producer-consumer model in my program. I have one thread which keeps enqueuing data to the queue, and one thread keeps dequeuing data from the queue. My question is do I need mutex lock for this scenario when doing enqueue or dequeue operation? Is it required? I see the need for mutex if I have more than one threads at producer or consumer side, but I am not sure if it is necessary for my case.

My code is as follows:

```
template <class T>
class myqueue {
private:

    queue<T> localqueue;
    boost::mutex insert;

public: 
    myqueue(){}
    ~myqueue(){}
    void enqueue(T in_value) {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock insert_lock = boost::mutex::scoped_lock(
                this->insert);
        localqueue.push(in_value);
        insert_lock.unlock();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to protect the enqueuing and dequeuing with a mutex if you want to avoid race conditions that could lead to UB.

Comment: Note not only enqueuing and dequeuing needs to be locked - There's more complicated problems beyond that like invalidated iterators and *size()* problems. I am not sure that the STL queue is the best starting point for implementing thread communications.

Answer (score 1):

A **s**ingle **p**roduce **s**ingle **c**onsumer can be done [lockfree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/lockfree.html). Try [`boost::lockfree::spsc_queue`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.html), which is explicitly for this  scenario.

> ```
> boost::lockfree::spsc_queue
>     a wait-free single-producer/single-consumer queue (commonly known as ringbuffer)
> ```

Comment: Note that one other requirement imposed by the lock-free implementation is that the maximum possible size of the queue must be specified in advance (i.e. the queue cannot be resized larger while the queue is in use, since there is no safe way to do so without using a lock)

Answer (score 1):

**Reading/writing the queue in parallel could lead to race conditions**.

So YES, every operation that modify/read the queue need a mutex.

[The following article is about  consumer-producer queue](http://vichargrave.com/multithreaded-work-queue-in-c/)